# Замена последней цифры(или буквы) строки

Tags: python

Всем привет! Python только начинаю изучать. Встал такой вопрос: нужно заменить последний символ каждой строки. Но что то делаю не так, синтаксическая ошибка:

```
#тут указываю файлы чтения и записи
    inp = open ('inp.txt', 'r')
    out = open ('out.txt', 'w')
#тут читаю файл построчно
    for line in inp:
#тут вывожу столбец в одну строку
        line = line.replace('\n', ',')
#тут делаем список из полученного
        sep = line.split(',')
#тут делаем срез последнего символа
        end = str('sep[-2:-1]')
#проверяем на равенство единице (тут выдает ошибку)
        if end == 1
#заменяем единицу на двойку
            end.replace (str(1),str (2))
#иначе если другой символ- заменяем на единицу
        else end.replace (str (1))
        out.write ()    
    inp.close ()    
    out.close ()
```

Comment: Если у вас в коде комментарии так и идут не на том уровне, что код, то конечно получите ошибку. Если не в этом проблема, укажите ошибку текстом прямо в вопросе.

Comment: И замените `end = str('sep[-2:-1]')` на `end = sep[-2:-1]`. По сути `str('sep[-2:-1]') == 'sep[-2:-1]'`, я думаю, это не то что вам нужно.

Comment: нет комментарии я уже тут дописал для ясности

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отступы и переносы строк в Python имеют очень большое значение. После начала цикла и условия нужно ставить двоеточие, а блок должен начинаться с новой строки и отступа.

К тому же алгоритм у вас достаточно мутный. Можно без метода `replace` обойтись.

```
#тут указываю файлы чтения и записи
with open('inp.txt') as inp, open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    #тут читаю файл построчно
    for line in inp:
        # Удаляем символы переноса строки с конца
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        # Записываем всю строку, кроме последнего символа
        out.write(line[:-1])
        # Проверяем последний символ
        if line[-1] == '1':
            out.write('2')
        else:
            out.write('1')
        # Добавляем перенос строки
        out.write('\n')
```

Comment: `out.write(line[:len(line) - 1])` можно записать просто как `out.write(line[:-1])`

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, поправил.

Comment: спасибо, скрипт работает, не совсем только понял что rstrip удаляет здесь \r

Comment: В разных ОС символы \r и \n означают перевод строки. http://www.softtime.ru/forum/read.php?id_forum=2&id_theme=72750

Comment: @jfs, благодарю, исправил